# How to convert Vec(n,Bool()) into UInt value

Tags: scala, chisel

As title, I want to covert Vec(Bool()) into UInt value.

For example

```
class MyModule extends Module {

  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val in_data    = Input (Vec (3, Bool() ) 
    val result     = Output(UInt(5.W))
  })

  //how can I convert io.in_data to Uint and the assign to io.result
  //I will get io.result = 7 when in_data(1, 1, 1) 
}
```

Comment: Question not clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.asUInt` to cast a Vec to Bools (or any Chisel Data) to UInt.

If you need to cast from UInt back to Vec or Bools you can use `.asBools`

Please see https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/cookbooks/cookbook.html